# Why does an integer variable in c after pasing charachter value to it print its old value?

Tags: c

While building a stack program with c, i found something weird(not for everyone but for a person who is working with web technology it is.) I used a choice variable (of integer type) and that manipulate a switch. and this happens in a loop as shown below in the snippet.

```
do {
    printf("\n\tEnter your choice for the operation: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    getchar();
    printf("%d", choice);
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        printf("\n\tEnter the token to be inserted:");
        token = getchar();
        push(token);
        show();
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        token = pop();
        if (TOP > -1)
            printf("\n\tThe token deleted is %c", token);
        show();
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        show();
        break;
    }
    default:
        printf("\n\tWrong choice");
        getchar();
    }
    printf("\n\tDo you want to continue(y/n): ");
    ch = getchar();
} while (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y');
```

Say You are running a Test case like this
[Sample Test Case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNBwZ.png)
In the second iteration when i pass the choice as a charachter why does the choice uses its old value that is 2?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, but text.

Comment: What is `scanf` *supposed* to do if it cannot interpret the input as a decimal integer?  It cannot use that input to assign a value to provided variable.  Perhaps you imagined that it would set some kind of default value, but in fact it simply leaves that variable alone.  You could have detected that via the function's return value, which tells you how many fields were successfully scanned and assigned.

Comment: @Swordfish okay sorry

Comment: @JohnBollinger I was just curious because i have read how programmer bad coding style may lead to hack his developed tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format `%d` in `scanf` accepts (consumes) character sequences that represent integers in decimal notation. If the characters you input do not match the required format, `scanf` fails and returns *without modifying the recipient variable*. This is what happened in your case. `i` is not valid input for format `%d`. `scanf` failed immediately and `choice` kept its old value.

Comment: Okay i thought it will generate some error, I think i first need to look the snippet of scanf, before posting it. But anyway thank you.

Comment: @Gaurav *Okay i thought it will generate some error* – It does, check the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: As mentioned in the second comment to your question, scanf() return value will return the number of fields that were successfully scanned.

Comment: @MarkJ.Bobak Thank you i get it. I understand JohnBollinger comment.

Answer (score 2):

Because ([C99 7.19.6.2p10](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.19.6.2p10), the emphasis is mine) `"i"` and `"%d"` cause a "matching failure".

> [...] the input item [...] is converted to a type appropriate to the conversion specifier. **If the input item is not a matching sequence, the execution of the directive fails: this condition is a matching failure**. [...]

You should always test the return value of most functions with prototype in `<stdio.h>`

```
if (scanf("%%", ...) != EXPECTED) /* error */;
```

Comment: does the EXPECTED is declared in stdio.h

Comment: @Gaurav *EXPECTED* is just a placeholder pmg put there. It is the number of conversions, `scanf()` should perform. e.g `int a; int b; if (scanf("%d %d", &a, &b) != 2) // handle error`